# hibernate filter using field from superclass

Tags: java, hibernate

I am trying to migrate my application from JBoss 7.1.1 using Hibernate 4.0.1.Final to JBoss EAP 6.2 which uses version 4.2.7.SP1.

I have the following hierarchy of entities:

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Filters({ @Filter(name = "deleted") })
@FilterDef(name = "deleted", defaultCondition = "deleted is null")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class Base implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date deleted;

    // getters/setters...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "actors"))
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Actor extends Base {

    private String name;

    // getters/setters...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User extends Actor {

    private String firstname;

    private String lastname;

    // getters/setters...
}
```

I want my app to filter out all objects having the 'deleted' property set to non-null value and for this purpose I use Hibernate filters:

```
session.enableFilter("deleted");
List<?> list = session.createQuery("from User").list();
// list contains only users with deleted == null
```

On Hibernate 4.0.1 everything works fine. But when I run it on the newer version I get the following error:

```
ERROR: ERROR: column user0_.deleted does not exist
  Position: 211
```

During the research I found the first version which breaks the code - 4.1.5.SP1. I also found it to be potentialy related with this enhancement:

https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-2394

Is it a bug (possibly introduced in 4.1.5.SP1 and not fixed until now, i.e. 4.3.5.Final) or is there another, more recommended way to implement my feature?